# ajax calendarextender Bug when selecting year 2014 shifts back to 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET Ajax calenderextender.

The dates are displaying ok, and everything looks good except the problem is that when I select 2014 from the years, the displayed months header shows 2013. Choosing 2015 or other years does not cause this problem to occur.

This happens only until I select the current year (2013). Once I select the current year I'm able to select future year.

I do not have any idea why it's not working first time I'm not sure is this a bug or known issue. Please let me know if anybody have an idea about this.

Comment: What is the base control you are using? what is the thechnology. IE JqueryUI, built-in asp.net user control? we need more details

Comment: I am also using this control and experiencing the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

In ur aspx page...

```
   <Ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    Pick a date: 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCal" runat="server"/>
    <Ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCal" SelectedDate="6/6/2012" StartDate="6/1/2012" EndDate="7/1/2012">
</Ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

Use this in Scripting

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowYears(sender,args)

{

sender._switchMode("years", true);           

 }

</script>
```

Again in your aspx page..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCalendar" runat="server"/> 
<asp:Image ID="imgCal" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png"/>
<Ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server"
                       TargetControlID="txtCalendar" 
                       PopupButtonID="imgCal" 
                       OnClientShown="ShowYears"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not the answer I'm looking for. I got the days and years displaying correctly. for example I was used start date today(03/05/2013) and end date is 03/04/2014. When I'm trying to select the date from calender extender it's always going to 2013 eventhough I clicked 2014. So I have to click 2013 year first then I'm able to click the year 2014. Why? and sorry for the confusion.